# Measure occurrences in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I was wondering whether it is possible (and if it is, the way) to perform the following task in Microsoft Access: there are two tables; first one consists of three columns 1) ID 2) tweet text and 3) date. Second table is a single vector of words, like a lexicon. **For every row** of the first table, I want to measure occurrences of the words of the second table (lexicon) in the tweet text column (2). Following, I want to add a new column in the first table, in which I will keep a record of these occurrences. My ultimate purpose is to perform some sort of sentiment analysis.

In case this helps, this is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tweet_data
WHERE Tweet_text LIKE "*" & Positive_sentiment & "*";
```

However, I most probably have to make some changes in the part following the `LIKE`

If you think there is a more practical way to perform such task (sentiment analysis) I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` in a `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tweet_data td LEFT JOIN
     Lexicon l
     ON td.Tweet_text LIKE "*" & l.Positive_sentiment & "*";
```

The part of your question on how to do sentiment analysis is too broad for Stack Overflow.  I will say, though, that MS Access is not the first tool that comes to mind.

EDIT:

The question is your comment is quite different from your actual question, but it is really a simple variation:

```
SELECT l.Positive_sentiment, count(td.tweet_text) as cnt
FROM Lexicon l LEFT JOIN
     Tweet_data td
     ON td.Tweet_text LIKE "*" & l.Positive_sentiment & "*";
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this query finds what tweets contain words from lexicon, I would like to cumulative occurrences of each word from the lexicon in the corresponding tweet_text

This is an example of what I am looking for:

Lets say I have these three tweets:
a) I love ice cream and I like summer
b) I like apples
c) I have no prior SQL knowledge so thanks very much

And the lexicon consists of the words 
1) Like
2) Love

My expected counter outcome should be like:
a) 2
b) 1
c) 0

Comment: @Demetris . . . You really should not ask new questions in the comments.  Instead, ask a new question.  In this case, the answer is similar enough that I added it in.